# Magento 2 - Display Regular price, special price and %discount

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to achieve this thing:
Showing the current regular price of a configurable product, and next to it the special price and the percentage of discount applied.

Apparently i can't get over it, and i swear i did google and search a lot everywhere.
I am trying to modify the final_price.html but with no good result so far.
The only thing i did was hiding the 'As low as' line before the price which was not needed.
but i can't understand how to display the regular and final as it should.

```
     <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
/** @var \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** @var \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPrice();
$minimalPrice = $finalPriceModel->getMinimalPrice();
$maximalPrice = $finalPriceModel->getMaximalPrice();
/** ex: \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Price\BundleRegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $regularPriceModel */
$regularPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');
$maximalRegularPrice = $regularPriceModel->getMaximalPrice();
$minimalRegularPrice = $regularPriceModel->getMinimalPrice();
?>
<?php if ($block->getSaleableItem()->getPriceView()): ?>
    <p class="minimal-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
            'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('from-'),
            'include_container' => true
        ]); ?>
        <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
            <span class="old-price">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                    'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'skip_adjustments'  => true
                ]); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($block->showRangePrice()): ?>
        <p class="price-from">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
                'display_label'     => __('From'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('from-'),
                'price_type'        => 'minPrice',
                'include_container' => true
            ]); ?>
            <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
                <span class="old-price">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                        'include_container' => true,
                        'skip_adjustments'  => true
                    ]); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif ?>
        </p>
        <p class="price-to">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($maximalPrice, [
                'display_label'     => __('To'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('to-'),
                'price_type'        => 'maxPrice',
                'include_container' => true
            ]); ?>
            <?php if ($maximalPrice < $maximalRegularPrice): ?>
                <span class="old-price">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($maximalRegularPrice, [
                        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                        'include_container' => true,
                        'skip_adjustments'  => true
                    ]); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif ?>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-'),
            'include_container' => true
        ]); ?>
        <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
            <span class="old-price">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                    'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'skip_adjustments'  => true
                ]); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to display the regular price of the bundle (including the regular prices of the selected options) and display something like (you saved 25.96 EUR or something like that). But I am not able to find out how or where to do that. Did you find a solution?